# Does my avatar affect my reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, gravatar, bias

Well, I'm wondering if a user with a silly or fun avatar is not considered as reputable as another.  Or the complete opposite...Having a default Gravatar mosaic image indicates the user is a noob, or doesn't interact enough with the community to care to define a custom avatar.

Personally, I hope everyone really enjoys my Tobais Fünké avatar.

Comment: Generally speaking the case is held that a person defines for themself a persona online, and that that persona has an instantly recognizable brand image. I would much rather follow someone with a known-to-me brand image, and their advice, rather than just someone who takes a good headshot.

Comment: @jcolebrand The logical problem then extending to the issue of people who happen to use the same known-to-you brand image. Don't see it often, but always a loop when it happens.

Comment: Surprise, I'm the top rated noob at SO.  I'll keep it.

Comment: Mosaic avatar looks good. No need to change.

Comment: I think it's not the avatar that defines you as a noob, it's the name. for example anybody called user12254568523 is a noob.

Comment: @DanielHanly given that user id is a SQL Server `int`, anyone with that exact username has in fact chosen it themselves...

Comment: @AakashM lol, sorry smartass, I'll be more careful with my numpad hammerings next time to ensure that they at least are within the range of `int`!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the list of [top users on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). Of users on the 1st page:

- 5 have default (mosaic) avatars.
- 13 have conventional head-shots.
- 1 has a decapitated head-shot.
- 1 has a head-shot of an anime character.
- 1 has a head-shot of a Simpsons character.
- 1 has a head-shot of a cat.
- 1 has a head-shot of an integrated circuit man.
- 1 has a head-shot of a cross between a human baby and a *narwhal*.
- 2 have head-shots of stick figures.
- 10 have various other objects or symbols, many of them silly.
- and founder and #1 user [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) has this: [image: Coding Horror logo]

In short, **having a quirky avatar does not hurt your reputation here.**

Comment: If this question can be answered, I think this is it.

Comment: And one has a QR code.

Answer (score 25):

> I'm wondering if a user with a silly or fun avatar is not considered as reputable as another.

It seems to be okay for these guys.

[image: gumbo]
[image: bobince]

> Having a default Gravatar mosaic image indicates the user is a noob, or doesn't interact enough with the community to care to define a custom avatar.

There is evidence that this is not the case.

[image: mmyers]

Comment: I resent that remark! Having a gravatar image that is not of one's self clearly indicates that .. one is .. oh screw it.

Comment: @jcolebrand is right, I'm clearly not to be trusted.

Comment: I'd submit that reputation points and diamonds are not a valid judge of whether or not I care enough to define a custom avatar. :P

Comment: @mmyers that's not a custom avatar? And here I thought it was

Comment: @mmyers: You really need to work on your interaction with the community.  It's like we don't even know you.  ;)

Comment: @Bill is setting the right example by showing a full body shot.

Comment: Gumbo's avatar is the greatest avatar ever!!

Comment: Neil B II's avatar was kind of, well .. umm .. O.k., so I don't have a term to describe that particular avatar, but he managed to hit 10k in a month or so.

Comment: Cletus' one is also pretty awesome :)

Answer (score 6):

Just look at some of the [Top Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). I notice that [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) and [Cletus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) seem to do fine on rep. :)

And [Cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) has 145K rep on the *main* site, too...

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I have found the best bet to be: [ask the community to make a gravatar for you](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/486075#486075). Then, randomly rotate through the submissions and you're bound to please everyone at some point!

(Sadly, most of the selections were removed from imgur. Here they are from my Gravatar account:)

*From [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand):*

[image: Popular Demand Gravatar]

*From [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek):*

[image: Micheal Mrozek Gravatar]

*From [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone):*

[image: Tim Stone Gravatar]

*From [Fosco](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150168/fosco):*

[image: Fosco Gravatar]

Comment: Hey, haven't seen you in a while! (I believe I submitted one too, but I can't find it.)

Comment: @Moshe I am slowly working my way out of the pile of work I am under. I shall make an official return soon! If you can find the Gravatar you created for me I will put it in here as well

Comment: The images are still viewable by adding `stack` to their URL. Like http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3F0d.png rather than http://i.imgur.com/Q3F0d.png

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your avatar and user name to something random like Jon Skeet and find a random head shot from Google images like this one

[image]

and see if it has any effect on your reputation.

Comment: I know you're joking, but it wouldn't be the first time we've had to remove imposter Jon Skeet accounts.

Comment: I am Jon Skeet.  This is a fake account just to pose this question!

Answer (score 4):

I would say that at the very least a ***"unique"*** avatar might allow you to be more easily recognizable to users, therefore swaying their opinion of your answer based on how they feel about your site interaction as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered this Simpson's "Nerd" is named Doug....

[image]

### Hello new avatar...

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to get any hard facts here, as there some preferences of certain avatar types might correlate with some other properties which might influence how good the posts are, or otherwise influence the votes.

You might want to do an experiment here:

- Create three new accounts.
- One account gets a "funny" image, one stays with the default Gravatar pattern, one gets a serious looking photo.
- Each time when you are about to post a question or answer, throw a dice to decide which of the three accounts to use.
- After about 100 (or 1000?) posts each, compare which got most upvotes/downvotes.

To exclude other factors, all three should have similar names. Or you might want to add different types of names, too: the default user920248 type, a real sounding name (not one already active on SO), a pseudonym like "OffBySome" (but again, not one already in use here).

This would be nine accounts, quite some work.

Comment: Hey dont use OffBySome! But OffByNone or OffByOne is all yours.

Comment: Actually, I'm not totally sure in which category my avatar is. It is a photo of myself, in some way.

Comment: @OffBy: Sorry, I needed an example here, and your post was just above to see. As I said, don't use a name which already is in use.

Comment: select * from SO where time on SO = 1 year and number questions asked = ~50  and number questions answered = ~50.  order by rep.  Review each image by hand

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I really never worried about my Gravatar.  I like my privacy online, so I didn't put up a headshot of myself (however grainy :P), but I just used something that represented something that I enjoyed...

My avatar is also rather unique and has sparked some interesting conversations - other people have seen it other places and thought of studiohack.

My two cents. :)